# How to use the function of "alerts" in shinyapp?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXn6Y.png)

I want to implement the information box in the picture. I checked his HTML code and found that he used a class called alert alert disallowed alert danger. I don't know how to use it in shinyapp. ps: I am a layman in HTML! Here is the html code:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <h3>Data privacy statement</h3>
                            <h4>The data you upload will <strong>NOT</strong> be stored, reused, or shared by us in any form.</h4>
                            </div>
```

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "lumen",version = 3),
                  
                  titlePanel("XXX"),
                  navbarPage("Let's get started",
                             tabPanel(icon("home"),
                                      
                                      fluidRow(
                                        column(8), 
                                  
                                        column(4,
                                          ## put notifications 
                                               h4("Links"),
                                               p("XXX",
                                                 style="text-align:justify;color:#3c763d;background-color:#dff0d8;padding:15px;border-radius:10px;
                                                 border-color:#d6e9c6"
                                               ),
                                               h4("Contact")
                                        )
                                      )
                             )
                  )
)
)
```

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/notifications.html or https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert

Comment: Thank you for your advice! The notifications is exactly the style of example, but I want notifications to be arranged in different columns of the page by line, not triggered by buttons. The code of these examples of notifications is written in the server. Can we write the content in the UI?

Comment: I added the  code of shinyapp, and you will clearly understand what I think